# Magento how to create different user login for different store

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have three different store (A, B, C) in one website and I want to create client user account for only one store A.

I mean client with the given login detail should be able to login only to the store A, he should not be able to see the store B/C.

How can I do that can any one help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to share clients in Magento, you need three different websites instead of stores.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent different websites on the same Magento installation from sharing customer data, go to `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options` and set the value to **Per Website**